# keras returning Attribute error 'Dense' object has no attribute '_saved_model_inputs_spec'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to upgrade a code from `tensorflow 1.x` to `tensorflow 2.x`, since I need to use it with `python>=3.8`. The code is from someone else who is not updating it, you can find it here if needed: https://github.com/NetManAIOps/donut.
I have used the tools provided by `tensorflow` to upgrade it (i.e. running `tf_upgrade_v2` in each file).
Already for a while I have been stuck with an error that I cannot track down.

```
 File "test_model.py", line 227, in <module>
   get_anomaly_score(test_files, KPI=args.KPI)
 File "test_model.py", line 79, in get_anomaly_score
   test_score = dm.predictor.get_score(test_values, test_missing)
 File "/home/miguel/gitlab_projects/test/donut_haowen/donut/prediction.py", line 138, in get_score
   b_r = sess.run(self._get_score(), feed_dict=feed_dict)
 File "/home/miguel/gitlab_projects/test/donut_haowen/donut/prediction.py", line 64, in _get_score
   self._score = self.model.get_score(
 File "/home/miguel/gitlab_projects/test/donut_haowen/donut/model.py", line 197, in get_score
   x_r = iterative_masked_reconstruct(
 File "/home/miguel/gitlab_projects/test/donut_haowen/donut/reconstruction.py", line 101, in iterative_masked_reconstruct
   x_r, _ = tf.while_loop(
 File "/home/miguel/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 629, in new_func
   return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/miguel/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2516, in while_loop_v2
   return while_loop(
 File "/home/miguel/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2716, in while_loop
   return while_v2.while_loop(
 File "/home/miguel/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/while_v2.py", line 222, in while_loop
   body_graph = func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
 File "/home/miguel/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1283, in func_graph_from_py_func
   func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
 File "/home/miguel/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/while_v2.py", line 200, in wrapped_body
   outputs = body(
 File "/home/miguel/gitlab_projects/test/donut_haowen/donut/reconstruction.py", line 103, in <lambda>
   body=lambda x_i, i: (masked_reconstruct(reconstruct, x_i, mask), i + 1),
 File "/home/miguel/gitlab_projects/test/donut_haowen/donut/reconstruction.py", line 65, in masked_reconstruct
   r_x = reconstruct(x)
 File "/home/miguel/gitlab_projects/test/src/tfsnippet/tfsnippet/modules/auto_encoders/vae.py", line 469, in reconstruct
   model = self.model(z=q_net['z'], n_z=n_z, n_x=n_x)
 File "/home/miguel/gitlab_projects/test/src/tfsnippet/tfsnippet/utils/reuse.py", line 179, in wrapper
   return method(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/miguel/gitlab_projects/test/src/tfsnippet/tfsnippet/modules/auto_encoders/vae.py", line 314, in model
   x_params = self.h_for_p_x(z)
 File "/home/miguel/gitlab_projects/test/src/tfsnippet/tfsnippet/modules/base.py", line 89, in __call__
   return self._forward(inputs, **kwargs)
 File "/home/miguel/gitlab_projects/test/src/tfsnippet/tfsnippet/modules/container/lambda_.py", line 47, in _forward
   return self._factory(inputs, **kwargs)
 File "/home/miguel/gitlab_projects/test/donut_haowen/donut/model.py", line 24, in wrap_params_net
   h = h_for_dist(inputs)
 File "/home/miguel/gitlab_projects/test/src/tfsnippet/tfsnippet/modules/base.py", line 89, in __call__
   return self._forward(inputs, **kwargs)
 File "/home/miguel/gitlab_projects/test/src/tfsnippet/tfsnippet/modules/container/sequential.py", line 76, in _forward
   outputs = c(outputs, **kwargs)
 File "/home/miguel/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
 File "/home/miguel/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1140, in __call__
   if self._saved_model_inputs_spec is None:
AttributeError: 'Dense' object has no attribute '_saved_model_inputs_spec'
```

This occurs when I call the predictor.py file in the `donut` package. This will call another package called `TFsnippet`, which I also upgraded, and this will finally call the keras package.
Since it is not my code that I am using I have trouble to write any kind of minimum reproducible example.

I am looking for any idea of where could the issue be, and what parts of the code should I maybe check. At the moment I do not have any idea of why or how this error occurs.

Please, tell me if I should add something.

Comment: Hi. best is to provide all infromation here on stack so it is still usefull later.
I would find it helpfull if you include a longer traceback (or ist that all?) - to see on which line in your code does it happen and what comes before.
If its really all try with the debuger to find the point where it jumps from your code to the part with the error.

Comment: Thank you. I just edited the question with this addition

Comment: The only thing I have found using the debugger is the following: there is a loop such that the line 1140 from the keras file that gives the AttributeError is executed more than once. The first time the execution works good and the name of the object is 'z_std' (which is given when calling the object in the "donut" model script). but in the next execution, which throws the error, the object name is 'dense'. In both cases the Type of the object is the same (keras.layers.core.dense.Dense), and the other attributes look the same